# Unix Shell Script to automatically generate an email alert

Tags: shell, email, unix

Developing a shell script, I am trying to send email and the recipient of the email should see an alias instead of email address in his mail box.
For example:

```
MAILTO="${recepients_list}"
CONTENT="${scr}/content.html"
SUBJECT="Alert"
(
 echo "To: $MAILTO"
 echo "From: example@xyz.com"
 echo "Subject: $SUBJECT"
 echo "Content-Type: text/html"
 echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
)
```

Instead of example@xyz.com email address, recipient should see alias "Example". Could you please tell me how I can get it? I can't update /etc/aliases file.

Comment: Have you tried `Example <example@xyz.com>`?

Comment: Thanks, It worked. I totally forgot it.

Comment: But still recipient will be able to see email address.  Is there any other way to hid email address?

Comment: No, there isn't a way to hide the email address completely.